# How do I get php to open a pdf file in a new tab?

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, pdf, file-upload

I don't understand the documentation I've been reading. Can anyone here explain how to do this?

I have a HTML link that goes to a function showFile(). There are two gets, an id, which is the file name, and an ext, the extension of the file.(Only extensions will be pdf, jpg, and gif) I'm using codeigniter framwework btw.

I read stuff about headers but when i tried that it just downloaded the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Function so far ---------

```
 public function showFile () {
    $fileId = $this->input->get('id');
    $fileExt = $this->input->get('ext');

}
```

Comment: Your browser may not have a PDF reader installed, hence the download.  If it's downloading as a PDF attachment and not spitting out binary vomit, your code is probably working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this in HTML:

```
<a href="downloadfile.php?filesrc=blah.pdf" target=_new>
    Click here to download blah.pdf</a>
```

Where of course the href has to be `echo`ed in PHP.

```
<a href="downloadfile.php?filesrc=<?php echo $filepath ?>" target=_new> ... </a>
```

Oh, and the downloadfile.php will simply have a `header('...');` redirect to the file.

Comment: I dont want it downloaded. I just want to to open in a new browser window.

Comment: Thats how you do that... The browser will ask the user if they want to view it or download it.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Files extends CI_Controller{

    public function show_file($id, $ext){
       $file_location = '';
       switch($ext){
           case 'pdf':
             $file_location = 'location-to_pdf_files'; // store as constant maybe inside index.php - PDF = 'uploads/pdf/';

             //must have PDF viewer installed in browser !
          $this->output
           ->set_content_type('application/pdf')
           ->set_output(file_get_contents($file_location . '/' . $id . '.pdf'));

           break;
           //jpg gif etc here...
       }

    }
}
```

-

```
$route['view/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'files/show_file/$1/$2';
```

-

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('view/picture/pdf');?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Some_file<a/>
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. If the file is downloading normally, it could be your browser. Try it with several browsers. If you can view pdf's in a tab on other sites and it isn't working on yours report back.

Comment: @AndyGroff yeah should work fine andy.  + users have the option to print or download the pdf, like you say though it depends on the browser