# How to open a pdf file in new tab from controller PHP (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5

Hi I am new to php programming. I am using laravel 5.2 now.

I have used an external service to create a pdf from my html page. For that I have used pdfcrowd. I wrote the content to a pdf file in my local system. Its location is `/var/www/html/testproject/test_pdf.pdf`.

It works fine. Now my requirement is that, I have to open that pdf file in a new tab from my controller. My controller name is adminController. Inside that I used a function to open the pdf.

Please see the code below:

```
public function open_pdf() {
  $file_location='/var/www/html/testproject/test_pdf.pdf';
  ----------?
}
```

Please suggest your ideas.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253839/how-do-i-get-php-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab

Comment: `<a href="/link/to/file" target="_blank">New tab</a>` You'll probably need to put the file in public directory though.

Comment: `<a href="/link/to/action_that_will_generate_pd_filef" target="_blank">New tab</a>` Then create a pdf and display to the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get php to open a pdf file in a new tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253839/how-do-i-get-php-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-a-new-tab)

Answer (score 4):

The important thing to understand is that, we can't open a new tab from php controller. So In the view page (testpage.blade.php) I used 'target="_blank" code in a tag. please see the code below:
 `<a href="{{ url('/') }}/testproject/openpdf"> target="_blank"`

Comment: It will not working well. Try <a href="{{ url('/') }}/testproject/openpdf" target="_blank">?

Comment: do you mean ```<a href="{{ url('/') }}/testproject/openpdf" target="_blank">```?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `target="_blank"` in your html  tags it will work fine.
You may have use like this

```
<a href="{{ url('/') }}/testproject/openpdf">
```

please try with this

```
<a href="{{ url('/') }}/testproject/openpdf" target="_blank">
```

Comment: I am using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf for PDF. Using Laravel 5.6.7. I have to display pdf is new tab. I have used window.open passing in the path, which is an api url. My big concern is, the url can be opened without authentication. If i use middleware auth in route, it tries to redirect to login, not able to see PDF. Please note that, I am not displaying a pdf file on public folder, but generating pdf using stream method. Please guide.